# How do I tell what program is keeping my hard drive spinning

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I've got a computer with both an SSD `C:` and a HDD `D:`, the latter previously used to (audibly) shut down when it was not in use.

For the last week or so, it doesn't ever shut down any more. Looking at task manager's disk usage, I see a couple of tiny spikes, so I assume it's a program that's sporadically reading from the HDD. How do I find out what program is doing this?

I tried using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)'s "Find handle or DLL" option, but that only shows that `explorer.exe` has a couple of handles on `D:`. I assume I always "miss" the small spikes when searching for handles.

Is there another way to find what I'm looking for?

Comment: Process Explorer's disc graph will show what program was generating the I/O if you hover over the spike.

Comment: @AFH Are you talking about [this graph](https://i.imgur.com/QQhoEGb.png)? Looks like that combines both disks unfortunately.

Comment: No, That's I/O, which combines all devices, disc, network, other comms devices, etc. There is a separate graph for disc only, though this will combine both discs, but the spikes should still give a good clue as to what is creating the activity.

Comment: On the I/O tab, I get 3 graphs, I/O, network and disc. I'm using Process Explorer 16.2, though I'm not even sure that's the latest - maybe you're using an earlier version? My version came with the SysInternals Suite.

Comment: @AFK I'm using the version downloaded from the link in the question, v16.21. I tried downloading the [SysInternals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) as well, it contains the same version. I tried running the 32-bit version, there the graph has [two colors](https://i.imgur.com/d8PjefE.png), although I'm not sure what they mean either.

Comment: Both 64- and 32-bit versions work similarly for me, and both show the 3 graphs. I think the two colours are probably read and write. You could also try `ProcMon` in the same suite and filter on names containing `D:`, although there may be other ways of accessing the drive, such as through a network address, which is why I didn't suggest this at the outset. Do you have swap space allocated on `D:`, by any chance?

Comment: @AFH Huh, I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/rR0bloP.png). Does that mean that something is querying the python, git and matlab folders? That's pretty random... As for swap, looks like there's only a bit allocated on `C:`, [img](https://i.imgur.com/U9Hihs8.png).

Comment: I can't see from the screen-shot, because of the path lengths, but do the file names give any clue? Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @AFH After looking around in the logs some more, turns out it was some kind of TeamViewer background service. If you post your `ProcMon` suggestion as an answer I'll accept that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process Explorer's disc graph will show what program was generating the I/O if you hover over the spike (in the case below, it's my anti-virus program).

[image: Disc Activity]

If this doesn't help you to home in on the problem, you could try the Process monitor `ProcMon`, which is also in the [SysInternals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), and filter on names starting with `D:\`, although there may be other ways of accessing the drive, such as through a network address (in my illustration below, I have no activity on `D:`, so I have shown anti-virus activity on `C:`).

[image: ProcMon Filter]

[image: Process Monitor]

Between these two tools you should be able to home in on what is originating your disc activity, and I learn from your comments that you have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look to Resource Monitor which files are opened, according this view you can find what processes works with those files. 
There is always way to start Windows in Safe mode and check if the problem persist or not. If not disable all unnecessary programs at startup (for ex. via CCleaner) and start them manually and look for a change.

Comment: Well searching for handles on the `D:` only results in `explorer.exe`: [img](https://i.imgur.com/IUV7oB1.png), but I'm not copying anything, nor do I have anything opened. Shouldn't startup programs that are using the HDD also show up here?

Comment: Any service (also 3rd party) can use explorer.exe for accessing files (indexing, antivirus search etc.) so opened file doesn't have to be used via specific .exe file but only explorer. Try Safe mode, where all unnecessary applications and services should be disabled.